# Disabling ciphers on ApacheDS 2.0

Tags: apacheds

We have an existing installation of ApacheDS 2.0 ib on a linux server (RPM installation). Been asked to disable 'weak ciphers'.

Is there any easy way of listing/disabling ciphers?

Thanks in advance.

Puneet